# How to Make Whole DIV a Link

Tags: html, css

I want to make a minimal landing page, where a whole screen is divided into 2 with text links to click through to each part of the site.

I figured out this much:

https://jsfiddle.net/m2ne5f3b/

I used 2 halves to create the divide, using a border on one side to create the line in the middle. It's super rudimentary.

```
.left-half {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.right-half {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Now what I want to do is make the whole of each half clickable, instead of the text only. Tried a couple different options to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the `<a>` the block! There is absolutely no need to use JS for this.

```
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="left-half">
    <article>
      <p>Google</p>
    </article>
  </a>
```

Then just style your `<a>` as a block because you are setting the height in your `.left-half` class, `<a>` elements are inline by default, so to make the `height` work, you need to make it a block:

```
.container a {
  display: block;
  // add any other CSS you want to apply
}
```

Working Snippet: Your Google looks exactly like the Youtube one in this, excelt that the whole block is now the link:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.left-half {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

section {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-half {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.right-half {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="left-half">
    <article>
      <p>Google</p>
    </article>
  </a>

  <div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a></p>
    </article>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: if a becomes the wrapper, there is no need to reset size or display, text-decoration and color is plent enough https://jsfiddle.net/m2ne5f3b/5/

Comment: @G-Cyr ok....? I'm not sure what you're trying to say? My example shows the OP how  they can change *their sepcific code* to make their `<a>` a block: the inner block-level element `<section>` didn't define the height, the `div.left-half` did. So when I changed it to `a.left-half`, their `<div>` styling had to be applied to explicitly to it.

Comment: I just meant you did not have to bother to style a , making it the wrapper is plenty enough.You can hover any child , <a> will also catch the hover event ;) , that's all i did with the fiddle link to shw how simple it is in fact. i react on the first sentence where block could only be the wrapper. block can confuse where one beginner would understand to reset display.

Comment: @G-Cyr Thats because you *added* a new `<a> `element... as I said in my comment, I *changed* the `<div>` to an `<a>`. There was no need to add extra elements, the existing one could jut be "repurposed".

Comment: I did not add the a ? , i made  the a child be the parent  wrapper . {<div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a></p>
    </article>
  </div>' turned into `<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <p>YouTube</p>
    </article>
  </div></a>`

Comment: @G-Cyr as did I... by replacing the div. The fewer unnecessary elements, the better.

Comment: you also said. _Just make the <a> the block!_ .... the wrapper or parent would avoid confusion. it is not about display, but HTML5 specifity not styling ;) as you of course meant ... it is obvious to us

Comment: @G-Cyr As I understand it, you code for the content, and apply CSS to that for the design - the `<a>` describes the *purpose* of the content, the CSS dictates its *display*. Adding extra divs purely for styling was frowned upon way back when I was learning this stuff anyway...

Comment: a can be used as a block container for that specific purpose . then if you need section, article or div container within for the semantic purpose it is another question. Answer here is wrap the whole block of content  within the a so it has its meaning and js can be left aside ... i repeat, your first sentence made me react here no more, no less .

Comment: @G-Cyr Well, that sentence was in reaction to the previous answer suggesting that the `<a>` wouldn't work and they'd have to use JS to do it... So maybe not the most appropriate choice of words, but I was trying to emphasise that the `<a>`could of course be used to make a "clickable block" (as opposed to meaning that it having to be styled as a block element... the CSS was actually unrelated to my first sentence).

Comment: Wow, thanks for this simple, elegant solution! Gotta learn all the little ins and outs of CSS still, but this worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to mofify your HTML structure, then you can use a pseudo to fill the entire area to be responding as the link.https://jsfiddle.net/m2ne5f3b/7/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  font-style:italic;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.container {

}

.left-half {
  position: absolute;
  display:table;
  top:0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  
}

.right-half {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  display:table;
}
 
a { color: inherit; 
  text-decoration: none;} 
 
  a:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="container">

 <div class="left-half">
     <article>
      <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>
    </article>
   </div>
   
  <div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a></p>
    </article>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

**Note:** if the page is meant to be 2 links side by side with little styling, then the html can be reduced to 2 links

```css
html {
  height: 100%;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  width: 100%;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  display: table;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  table-layout: fixed;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: tomato;
}

body {
  display: table-row;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
}

a {
  display: table-cell;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  text-align: center;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  vertical-align: middle;/* necessary for the table-layout box model demo */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px
}

a:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(255, 114, 25, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

your common a tags arent going to cut it here. Your best bet is to use Javascript or jquery function calls on the divs.

```
<div class='left-half' onclick="fakeLink()" > 
<!-- some stuff here in the div -->
</div>
```

then in the script file

```
function fakeLink() {
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/link";
}
```

Comment: HTML 5 allows `<a>` tags to wrap block elements, so there is no need for JS to do this.

Comment: Sadly all browsers aren't HTML 5 compliant, but it is good to know, documentation?

Comment: I can't think of one modern browser that isn't HTML5 compatible... you could even make IE6 handle the unknown HTML5 elements! [HTML5 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element): "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)"

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  font-style:italic;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-half {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  
}

.right-half {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}
 
a { color: inherit; 
  text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="left-half">
      <article>
        <p>Google</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com">    
    <div class="right-half">
      <article>
        <p>YouTube</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```